# Regular expression for no whitespaces on the first position

Tags: java, regex

Example accepted:

> ```
> This is a try!
> And this is the second line!
> ```

Example not accepted:

> ```
>       this is a try with initial spaces
> and this the second line
> ```

So, I need:

- no string made only by whitespaces " "
- no string where first char is whitespace
- new lines are ok; only the first character cannot be a new line

I was using

```
^(?=\s*\S).*$
```

but that pattern can't allow new lines.

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: `\s*` allows any number of whitespaces though.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: So only the beginning of the very first line must not be whitespace, everywhere else whitespace is OK? Is the empty string `""` allowed or not?

Comment: Yes, the first character of the first line must not be whitespace or new line. All the other can be everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex

```
^(?!\s*$|\s).*$
    ---- -- --
      |   |  |->matches everything!
      |   |->no string where first char is whitespace
      |->no string made only by whitespaces
```

you need to use `singleline` mode ..

---

you can try it [here](http://fiddle.re/nwy7)..you need to use `matches` method

Comment: but I need it for multi lines... why singleline mode?

Answer (score 2):

"no string made only by whitespaces" is the same to "no string where first char is whitespace" as it also begins with white space.

You have to set `Pattern.MULTILINE` which changes the meaning of ^ and $ also to begin and end of line, not only entire string

```
"^\\S.+$"
```

Comment: I'm using this regex with Hibernate Pattern Validator for Struts2. But i don't know how can I set the MULTILINE property from Hibernate library. Someone know how can I do it?
I do: 
@Pattern(regex="^\\S.+$", flags=)
How can I set the flag? Pattern.MULTILINE is not recognized.

Comment: @MrMoog: Try just `m` or something (`flags=m`)

Comment: flags field takes an int, so I tried with @Pattern(regex="^\\S.+$", flags=java.util.regex.Pattern.MULTILINE, where I found that MULTILINE is 0x08 int value), but it don't works. I think that flag option has not been developed in the strut2-hibernate plugin!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java guy, but a solution in Python could look like this here:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: example_accepted = 'This is a try!\nAnd this is the second line!'

In [3]: example_not_accepted = '   This is a try with initial spaces\nand this the second line'

In [4]: pattern = re.compile(r"""
  ....:     ^     # matches at the beginning of a string
  ....:     \S    # matches any non-whitespace character
  ....:     .+    # matches one or more arbitrary characters
  ....:     $     # matches at the end of a string
  ....:     """,
  ....:     flags=re.MULTILINE|re.VERBOSE)

In [5]: pattern.findall(example_accepted)
Out[5]: ['This is a try!', 'And this is the second line!']

In [6]: pattern.findall(example_not_accepted)
Out[6]: ['and this the second line']
```

The key part here is the flag `re.MULTILINE`. With this flag enabled, `^` and `$` do not only match at the beginning and end of a string, but also at the beginning and end of lines which are separated by newlines. I'm sure there is something equivalent for Java as well.